# phone goes black when I switch between activities and activities are created more than once in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, navigation-drawer

whenever I use intent to switch to another activity the next activity gets created 3times and goes black before creation,
I am currently struggling with my main navigation activity
I am trying to launch it from my login activity. I have  tried everything.

this is my intent code

```
  Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this,MainNavigation.class);
                                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
```

this is my navigation activity code:

```
public class MainNavigation extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    LinearLayout container;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    TextView logoutView;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    SharedPreferences shpall;
    SharedPreferences.Editor shediteallr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_navigation);



    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        shpall=getSharedPreferences("saveUsersforall",MODE_PRIVATE);
        shediteallr=shpall.edit();


        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


        logoutView=findViewById(R.id.logout);

        logoutView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                shediteallr.clear();
                shediteallr.apply();
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return false;
            }
        });

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(  this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);


        toolbar.getOverflowIcon().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK , PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

        toggle.syncState();
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.




        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navigations_fragment_container,new HomeFragment()).commit();


        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_add_property:
                    {
                        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    }
                    break;

                    case R.id.nav_list:
                    {
                        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        //connecting activity with fargment

                    }

                    case R.id.nav_about_us:
                    {
                        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                    }
                    break;
                    case R.id.nav_contact_us:
                    {
                        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    }
                    break;


                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_navigation, menu);
        return true;
    }
/*
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

 */



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_library:
            {
                //for report
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navigations_fragment_container,new LibraryFragment()).commit();

            }
            break;

            case R.id.nav_home:
            {
                //connecting activity with fargment
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navigations_fragment_container,new HomeFragment()).commit();
            }
            break;

            case R.id.nav_account:
            {
                //for account
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navigations_fragment_container,new Pro`enter code here`fileFragmen`enter code here`t()).commit();

            }
            break;

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe show us some of your code? Does the activity start properly eventually or does it fail? Are all your activities added to your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please add minimal raproducible example (read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ).

Comment: @Vanheden no it works properly , I tried using threads ,putting my code on(OnPostResume) ,I tried using intent Flags ,but nothing worked, I want to know what cousing this proplem.

Comment: @Vanheden I edited my question ,I inserted my code

Comment: Do you use an onTouchListener for your button that forward you to the navigation page? I'm no super expert but maybe "Login" gets called multiple times (OnTouchListener register when you press down on a button AND then gets called again when you lift your finger from the button etc, at least if you consume the down click. Perhaps an OnClickListener would be enough to use instead since you don't seem to do anything with the MotionEvent. Also..I would set up all the views in onCreate() in an Activity or onCreateView() in a fragment.

Comment: You could also try intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); instead and see if it makes any diffrence. That is what I use to clear all previous activities from the stack and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Vanheden oh thank you ,I was using on Touch click listener  ,it was the reason so many activities were running at the same time ,plus I fixed the black screen by changing my theme to light theme and using white color on primary .

Answer (score 0):

To help potential future visitors with the same problem, the answer to this was that an incorrect implementation of OnTouchListener lead to "Login" being called multiple times creating several new activities instead of just the one (because OnTouchListeners onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) is being called at least 2 times in a button click and you would need to use to MotionEvent to make sure you only do the "click action" once).

Implementing an OnClickListener instead removed the multiple initiations of the same activity but you could also implement an OnTouchListener with an onTouch() method that looks something like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(e.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        doYourClickAction();
        v.performClick();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But that seems unnecessary in this case because you basically just turn it in to a regular OnClickListener, but this is what was missing and which made it create multiple instances of the activity which in turn will demand to much from the main thread to build them all at the same time.